# How to parse string correctly into onclick method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic table which is being created with jquery. The problem I face is, jquery interferes my string so it's not being parsed correctly to onclick method.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.result.list.length; i++) 
{
    var tr = $("<tr></tr>");                       
    tr.append("<td>" + "<a onclick='" + data.result.list[i].cfunction + "'>" + data.result.list[i].cvalue + "</a>" + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + + "</td>");
    table.append(tr);
}
```

`data.result.list[i].cfunction` has a string value like `"getMyMethod('My parameter')"` which is basically calling a method with parameter in quotes.
But after jQuery parses this to `onclick` function it's value changes as  `onclick="getMyMethod(" my="" parameter')'=""`

here is the generated html:

```
<a onclick="getMyMethod(" my="" parameter')'="" >My Value</a>
```

Can anyone put me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you show the generated HTML?

Comment: Please post code regarding how you get your `data`. via Ajax call??

Comment: @31piy I added it. Do you think is it clear?

Comment: can you log data.result.list[i].cfunction ?

Comment: use  escape like `alert("\"Hello\"");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
  "<a onclick='" + data.result.list[i].cfunction + "'>"
```

to this

```
  '<a onclick="' + data.result.list[i].cfunction + '">'
```

Answer (score 1):

You internal double quotes `"` needs to be escaped

```
var func = data.result.list[i].cfunction.replace( /"/g, "\\\"" );
tr.append("<td>" + "<a onclick='" + func + "'>" + data.result.list[i].cvalue + "</a>" + "</td>");
```

Comment: Hello, internal double quotes are being generated as I'm parsing it to onclick function. There's no internal double quotes in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

you should modify code with:

```
tr.append(
    $("<td></<td>").append(
        $("<a></a>")
            .attr({
                "href" : "#"
            })
            .text(data.result.list[i].cvalue)
            .attr({
                "onclick" : data.result.list[i].cfunction
            })
    )
);
```

Comment: although I've marked another answer as accepted, I find this approach more readable and better, thanks a lot for providing this.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your cfunction items in the data like this (encode):

```
cfunction: "getMyMethod(\"My parameter\")",
```

This worked in the console (make sure the table ID exists):

```
var data = {
    result: {
        list: [
            {
                cfunction: "getMyMethod(\"My parameter 1\")",
                cvalue: "1"
            },
            {
                cfunction: "getMyMethod(\"My parameter 2\")",
                cvalue: "2"
            }
        ]
    }
}

var table = $("#testTable");

for (var i = 0; i < data.result.list.length; i++) {
    var tr = $("<tr></tr>");                       
    tr.append("<td>" + "<a onclick='" + data.result.list[i].cfunction + "'>" + data.result.list[i].cvalue + "</a>" + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + + "</td>");
    table.append(tr);
}

var getMyMethod = function (funcParam) {
    console.log(funcParam);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this. And be sure your `data.result.list[i].cfunction`  value is 
`"getMyMethod('My parameter')"`

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.result.list.length; i++) 
{
    var tr = $("<tr></tr>");                       
    tr.append("<td>" + "<a onclick=\" " + data.result.list[i].cfunction + 
"\" >" + data.result.list[i].cvalue + "</a>" + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + + "</td>");
    table.append(tr);
}
```